# NoSuchMethodError android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a serious problem. after making a test using espresso when I ran the test this complex error appears

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   setFactory2(Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;Landroid/view/LayoutInflater$Factory2;)V
>   in class Landroid/support/v4/view/LayoutInflaterCompat; or its super
>   classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompat'
>   appears in
>   /data/app/com.example.master.bakingapp.test-ZVHwTuzx1ipxW0iPyBZKBw==/base.apk)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.installViewFactory(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1299)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:72)
>   at
>   com.example.master.bakingapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136) at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>   at
>   android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:667)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>   at
>   android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>   at
>   android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>   at
>   android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>
> Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process
>   crashed.'

it's Pointed to onCreate on my MainActivity

> at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:72)
>   at
>   com.example.master.bakingapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)

I tried to debug my test. and it's stuck in onCreate

and this is my whole test code

```
package com.example.master.bakingapp;

import android.support.test.espresso.Espresso;
import android.support.test.espresso.IdlingResource;
import android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions;
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onData;
import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.anything;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ClickUiTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);
    private static final String RECIPE_ITEM_BROWNIE = "Brownies";
    private IdlingResource mIdlingResource;

    // Registers any resource that needs to be synchronized with Espresso before the test is run.
    @Before
    public void registerIdlingResource() {
        mIdlingResource = mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getIdlingResource();
        // To prove that the test fails, omit this call:
        Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
    }

    @Test
    public void checkSelectedItem_InRecycleView() {

        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.recycle_recipe)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(1));
        onView(withId(R.id.Ingredient_TextView)).check(matches(withText(RECIPE_ITEM_BROWNIE)));
    }

    @After
    public void unregisterIdlingResource() {
        if (mIdlingResource != null) {
            Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
        }

    }
}
```

and gradle module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.master.bakingapp"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/androidTest'] } }
}
ext {
    lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
    butterLibVersion = '8.8.1'
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:${lifecycle_version}"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.0.1'
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${butterLibVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${butterLibVersion}"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2')
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.0.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'

    implementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.0.1'


}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecipeCardFragment.OnRecycleClick
{
    private Recipes[] mRecipes;
    MyViewModel mViewModel;
    String json;
    public static final String mURL = "https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/baking.json";
    public static final String Bundle_Object = "BUNDLE_OBJ";
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    RecipeCardFragment cardFragment;
    boolean mTabletbool;
    @Nullable
    private SimpleIdlingResource mIdlingResource;

    /**
     * Only called from test, creates and returns a new {@link SimpleIdlingResource}.
     */
    @VisibleForTesting
    @NonNull
    public IdlingResource getIdlingResource() {
        if (mIdlingResource == null) {
            mIdlingResource = new SimpleIdlingResource();
        }
        return mIdlingResource;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getIdlingResource();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onclick(int pos) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StepsActivity.class);
        try {
            Recipes recipes;
            recipes = Networkutils.ParseJsonIndex(json, pos);
            //updateWidget(recipes);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable(Bundle_Object, recipes);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            fragmentManager=null;
            cardFragment=null;
            startActivity(intent);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void jsonPass(String json) {
        this.json=json;
    }

    private void updateWidget(Recipes recipes) {
        ArrayList<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Ingredients ingre:recipes.getIngredients()){
            String q=ingre.getQuantity()+"";
            ingredients.add(ingre.getIngredient()+"\n"+
                    "Quantity: "+q+"\n"+
                    "Measure: "+ingre.getMeasure()+"\n");
        }
        UpdateBakingService.startBakingService(MainActivity.this,ingredients);
    }
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.example.master.bakingapp.Fragments.RecipeCardFragment"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

and my Fragment hosted by MainActivity

```
public class RecipeCardFragment extends android.app.Fragment {

    public interface OnRecycleClick {
        void onclick(int pos);
        void jsonPass(String json);
    }
    private OnRecycleClick mOnRecycleClick;
    Recipes[] mRecipes;
    boolean mTablet;

    //MainActivity

    MyViewModel mViewModel;
    String json;
    public static final String mURL = "https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/baking.json";
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ////


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mOnRecycleClick=(OnRecycleClick) context;
        }catch (ClassCastException e){
            //TODO therows new Execption
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable  ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipe_recycle,container,false);
       final RecyclerView recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_recipe);
        //final Context context=container.getContext();
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            mRecipes= (Recipes[]) savedInstanceState.getParcelableArray("Recipes");
        }

         final SimpleIdlingResource idlingResource = new SimpleIdlingResource();

        if (idlingResource != null) {
            idlingResource.setIdleState(false);
        }
       URL url=null;
        try {
            url=new URL(mURL);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        new AsyncTask<URL, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
                String jsons="";
                try {

                    jsons= Networkutils.HttpRequest(urls[0]);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return jsons;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
                super.onPostExecute(json);
                try {
                    mRecipes = Networkutils.parseRecipeCard(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                RecipeCardAdapter recipeCardAdapter= new RecipeCardAdapter(mRecipes,mOnRecycleClick);
                mOnRecycleClick.jsonPass(json);
                if(mTablet){
                    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new
                            GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recipeCardAdapter);
                }
                else {
                    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
                    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recipeCardAdapter);
                }
                if (idlingResource != null) {
                    idlingResource.setIdleState(true);
                }
            }
        }.execute(url);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArray("Recipes",mRecipes);
    }
}
```

NOTE: when I change my MainActivity to extends Activity instead of AppCompatActivity it's worked but I have too many support version

I did not solve this problem in 3 days. I really need help

Comment: So it sounds like maybe your version of Espresso doesn't completely support AppCompatActivity?  Look [here](https://medium.com/android-testing-daily/using-reflection-to-set-mock-android-dependencies-701571a22c92)

Answer (score 0):

OK: "setFactory2()" is *NOT* static; it should be a member of an LayoutInflator class instance.  For example:

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.view.LayoutInflater&method=setFactory2

```
static void setFactory(LayoutInflater inflater, LayoutInflaterFactory factory) {
    Factory2 factory2 = factory != null ? new FactoryWrapperHC(factory) : null;
    inflater.setFactory2(factory2);
    Factory f = inflater.getFactory();
    if (f instanceof Factory2) {
        forceSetFactory2(inflater, (Factory2) f);
    } else {
        forceSetFactory2(inflater, factory2);
    }
}
```

SUGGESTIONS:

Q: Do you have (an XML) layout?  Is it (are they) configured correctly?

Q: Does your Android app work standalone (independent of espresso)?

Comment: i posted my MainActivity and xml layout